# Menu bar clock disappears when try to show seconds in 24 hour format

Tags: 16.04, panel, clock

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I select 12 hour format in time and date settings, I can show seconds on the top panel clock.

[image][image]

When I choose 24 hour format and select seconds, the menu bar clock disappears.

[image][image]

This is not a big deal, but there is a problem. Can you explain this?

Comment: Personally, I think this is a bug, because this works on my system alright.

Comment: @Serg this worked on my system too, this is something mysterious happened recently.

Comment: well, software isn't perfect , it can crash sometimes. Is this a persistent issue ? Maybe it has been fixed with recent update , since you're not seeing it anymore

Comment: Actually this happened after installing and uninstalling several desktop environments like gnome, kde, I wanted to test them, but they messed up my Ubuntu